# PHP Application Flow Graph (or function call graph)

Tags: php, function, draw, graphviz, flowchart

Happens that I've ended up working on a big PHP program and I need a program (or easy to install script) which draws a flow control/call graph of a PHP application (ie; must work over multiple PHP files).
Already saw stuff like Graphviz, not sure which one works for PHP?

Any suggestions?

Cheers!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have never used any tool that can do that statically *(i.e. from source files)*, but here's a way to get a callgraph when executing a script/application.

First, you need to install the [**Xdebug extension**](https://xdebug.org/) -- on a development/testing server *(don't install it on a production server : it's quite bad for performances ^^ )*

Then, you can use its [profiling features](https://xdebug.org/docs/index.php?action=profiler) to generate a `.cachegrindout` file corresponding to the execution of a page-load.

After that, you can load that `.cachegrindout` file with [**KCacheGrind**](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html) *(On linux -- I don't think there's a windows version)* ; KCacheGrind can generate call-graphs from `.cachegrindout` files.

And here's an example of callgraph you can get :

[image: KCacheGrind : Callgraph exported as an image]
<sub>(source: [pascal-martin.fr](http://extern.pascal-martin.fr/so/kcachegrind/kcachegrind-2-small.png))</sub>

*(Here's, it's been generated from a `.cachegrindout` file obtained while loading a page of Dotclear, a blogging software)*

Comment: Neat!!

I could try this at home on my linux VM with a test PHP server.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

[Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org) can do it statically. Just doxygen -d to create a config file, then edit it to create callgraphs.