# Way to analyse PHPUnit tests with Webgrind or other PHP profiling tool?

Tags: php, profiling, phpunit

Profiling an entire application can be good for macro optimizations. But sometimes I want to optimize a specific package or library without other components interacting, with total isolation.

So I was thinking if phpunit has output for profiling tools like [Webgrind](https://github.com/jokkedk/webgrind)? Or at least is there a way to generate call graphs and performance reports from code executed in my unit tests?

> Please don't suggest to use `microtime()` or other php time functions
>   and make manual benchmarks, this is too error prone.

Answer (score 3):

- http://www.phpclasses.org/package/6688-PHP-Generate-call-graphs-of-PHP-code-with-GraphViz.html
- *DUP* of this [PHP call graph utility?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235513/php-call-graph-utility)
- *DUP* of this [PHP Application Flow Graph (or function call graph)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719734/php-application-flow-graph-or-function-call-graph)

webgrind takes data from [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/).   You may want to [read this](http://morgamic.com/2008/06/12/profiling-php-with-xdebug-and-webgrind/)

You probably also want to look at [newRelic](http://newrelic.com/php) ~ if the PHP runs a webapp.

How do I set the 'dup' flag?

Comment: "Profiling an entire application can be good for macro optimizations. But sometimes I want to optimize a specific package or library without other components interacting" - No, I want to optimize my tested code not the testing code.